# How to pass the changed value of a variable from a method to a condition in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I check Internet access like this:

My code on the main page:

```dart
class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {
  CheckUserConnection _checkUserConnection = CheckUserConnection();
  InternetDialogHandler _internetDialogHandler = InternetDialogHandler();
  bool? _internetAvailable;
...


void checkNet() async{
    _internetAvailable = await
    _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
    setState((){});
  }
```

My code on a different page because it is used on multiple screens.

```dart
class CheckUserConnection {

  Future checkInternetAvailability() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

This works well, but there is a problem when checkNet() checks for Internet availability before a condition that has _internetAvailable.

In particular:

```dart
GradientButton(label: 'Continue Game', onTap: () {
                    checkNet();
                    _loadData();
                    return _internetAvailable == true ?
                    {Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Game(
                          listCount: _listCount, assetPath: assetPath ///What I want to pass
                      )),
                    )}
                        :
                    _internetDialogHandler.showInternetDialog(context);
                  }),
```

The situation is the following. First, there is Internet access. Respectively,
_internetAvailable=true.

Then I specifically turn off Internet access and press the button.
checkNet() will check _internetAvailable and leave this variable set to true. Accordingly, the condition is met. And this is wrong.

But when I click on the button next time, _internetAvailable takes the correct value, i.e. false.

My question is the following. Where am I making a mistake? I want checkNet() to change the value of _internetAvailable the first time correctly.

And yes, the problem is not in the Internet access. As an experiment, I used other variables. For example, _isFirstLoad = true. The situation is the same. The first time the button is pressed, the value of the variable does not change.

Comment: This could be helpful https://medium.com/@nabin.dhakal/check-internet-connection-in-flutter-610647fefd68

Comment: Thank you. But, as I wrote in the last paragraph, this is not just about Internet access. I get this error whenever I call a method on a button click that should change the value of a variable, which is then a condition. Obviously, I make a mistake that the action doesn't fire the first time. But all subsequent times it works perfectly. And I want to understand where my mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Use **checkInternetAvailability()** like this

```
class CheckUserConnection {

      Future<bool> checkInternetAvailability() async {
        try {
          final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
          if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
            return true;
          }
        } on SocketException catch (_) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I add <bool> there, then I get the following error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<bool>', is a potentially non-nullable type. (Documentation)  Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Comment: set your bool _internetAvailable = false; like this.